# How to create a USB STACK using win32 programming

Tags: usb

I am doing my Project using win 32 programming.I am just learning about win32 programming and able to create an UI.I want to communicate with an USB Device with that UI.SO,How can i go for that?Is there any predefined functions will be there are we need to create the function for communicating with the OS and get the devices List and got the details about them.

My purpose is to ,

1.Creating an UI that tells about the Basic information about the device.

2.For that first of all i want to communicate with the OS for device attachment and find the drivers for that.That will lead to get the information about the device and communicate with the device using that UI.

So,can anyone help me about this?How can i achieve this or approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your USB Device enumerates as a vendor specific device and not a class that has a preloaded driver [WinUSB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be perfect for your case. If it is loading a class driver such as HID or some other class you will need to look up the API for that type of device on MSDN.